# What is the proper way to map .html to the ASP.NET pipeline in IIS7

Tags: iis-7

I have a .net application I want to respond to .htm and .html requests (in addition to .aspx). I know how to do this in IIS6, but not in IIS7. Someone please enlighten me!

Thanks,

Kyle

Comment: in windows features do you have "static content" feature installed?

Answer (score 1):

[This web site](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/508/wildcard-script-mapping-and-iis-7-integrated-pipeline/) has a tutorial that will probably get you moving in the right direction.

Comment: +1, though I'm not sure if the wild card mapping is the best way to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

In the *Features View* for the site or virtual directory you want this to apply to, look for the **Handler Mappings** icon in the lower *IIS* section.  Double click that to get into the actual list of handlers currently mapped.  You should theoretically see existing entries for things like *.aspx.  Double click the *.aspx one and use it as an example to create a new mapping for *.html.  The **Add Script Map** in the right hand pane is what you should use for this particular entry.

You can also do this in the web.config file directly.  But it's probably easier to just do it via the GUI first and then look at the resulting web.config file to see what changes were actually made.